# Symfony2 - display form error in bootstrap tooltip

Tags: forms, symfony, tooltip

I would like to display form error message inside bootstrap tooltip.

```
<div class="btn-upload" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-title="{% if document.documentFile.vars.errors|length > 0 %}<span class='text-danger'>{{ form_errors(document.documentFile) }}</span>{% endif %}">
```

It should display form error inside tooltip on icon.

But message is displayed like this:

[image]

Now if I change `{{ form_errors(document.documentFile) }}` to "TEST MESSAGE":

[image]

So the problem is form error rendering inside tooltip. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a simplier way to achieve it by foreaching errors of `document.documentFile.vars.errors`. A little bit similar way to Favian's answer but without rewriting a block.

```
<div class="btn-upload" data-toggle="tooltip" 
{% if document.documentFile.vars.errors|length > 0 %}
    data-html="true" 
    data-title="<span class='text-danger'>
        {% for error in document.documentFile.vars.errors %}
            {{ error.message }}
        {% endfor %}
    </span>"
{% endif %}
>
```

Works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

By default, the errors are rendered inside an unordered list:

```
<ul>
    <li>The file is to large bla bla bla</li>
</ul>
```

To override how errors are rendered for all fields, simply copy, paste and customize the form_errors fragment.

```
    <div class="btn-upload" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-title="{% if document.documentFile.vars.errors|length > 0 %}<span class='text-danger'>
        {% block form_errors %}
            {% spaceless %}
                {% if errors|length > 0 %}
                    {% for error in document.documentFile %}
                    {{ error.message }}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endspaceless %}
        {% endblock form_errors %}
     </span>{% endif %}">
</div>
```

Comment: overwriting whole block is not what I want. Anyway I resolved the problem in similar way but without rewriting the template.

Comment: you did a theme ? and call it ?

Comment: Check newest answer I did.

Comment: When I copied your code I get error that variable errors does not exist. So your code is not working in first place. Then I really do not want to overwrite the form_errors block because I display multiple form errors in same page in different way. I found an easier solution.

Comment: @Ignas-Damunskis Now should work :)) but no problem , happy you found a solution .

Answer (score 0):

The `{{ form_errors(document.documentFile) }}` renders HTML with `"` that breaks your div.

Consider doing this :

```
<div class="btn-upload" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" id="error-tooltip">
    <script type="text/html" id="form-error">
    {% if document.documentFile.vars.errors|length > 0 %}
        <span class='text-danger'>{{ form_errors(document.documentFile) }}</span>
    {% endif %}
    </script>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

And, in your JS :

```
$('#error-tooltip').data('tooltip', $('#form-error').html());
```

Comment: I resolved it a bit simplier. THank you for your input anyway!